# Rewriting complex exponential as trig functions

Tags: python, sympy, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I want to rewrite complex exponentials as trig functions like you see in this picture: [image]

My attempt with e^(2 pi I / 8) is not working, because it instantly converts it to square roots:

```
from sympy import E, pi, I, re

root = E**(2 * pi * I / 8)
print(root)
print(root.rewrite(cos))
print(re(root).rewrite(cos))
```

From these print statements I get:

> exp(I*pi/4)
>
> sqrt(2)/2 + sqrt(2)*I/2
>
> sqrt(2)/2

I want to get cos(2 pi/8) for the real part, and sin(2 pi/8) for the imaginary part.  But as you can see, it directly evaluates to square roots.  How can I get the trig representation?

Comment: You're assuming that sympy has been programmed to understand these identities.  I don't think anyone promised that.  Also, your example has `6/8*pi*i`, not `2/8*pi*i`.

Comment: Fixed the typos in the equation

Comment: Use [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org/) instead? =/

Comment: I'm missing the larger context, but would something like `arccos(re(E**(2 * pi * I / 8)))` work?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky, but you could define your own symbol for pi instead of using sympy.pi to avoid having the cosine and sine actually evaluated:

```py
from sympy import E, I, symbols, cos
mypi = symbols("pi")
root = E**(2 * mypi * I / 8)
print(root)
print(root.rewrite(cos))
```

Output:

```
exp(I*pi/4)
I*sin(pi/4) + cos(pi/4)
```